# Configure a callback URL to your server for the LinkedIn API

Tags: http, callback, linkedin-api

I am very new to the API scene. I am trying to set up a simple app using the LinkedIn API. I have made an app and now I need to [configure a callback URL to your server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin/context#step-1-get-client-id-and-client-secret).

I am not sure I understand what I am supposed to do. Ideally, this script will run locally and not on a server. I also do not have a server. What can I do to set this up such that I can make those HTTP Post requests and return real data?

Thank you!